# Firebase auth - login user from app in website

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

We have an App that uses firebase auth. Now we would like to send the user from the app  to our website in order for him to perform some actions.

Is it somehow possible to automatically login the user when he comes from the App? He has already provided his login credentials and we have the auth object from firebase. Can we pass a token or somthing to our website and have the firebase SDK on the site log him automatically?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The common way to do this right now is as follows:

1. After the user signs in in one website, get the ID token via `currentUser.getIdToken()`
2. Post the ID token to your backend to serve the destination website.
3. On your backend, using Admin SDK, get the ID token, verify it, check the auth_time to make sure it is a recent login to minimize any window of attack. If everything checks out, mint a custom token via admin sdk `createCustomToken`.
4. Return the custom token to the website.
5. On the client side, sign in with custom token: `signInWithCustomToken` and the same user is now signed in on the website.

Comment: Ah, okay! I see! Now the official docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens make sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this a bit easier, without having my own backend server to create a custom token, as long as you are using Google auth. It might work for other providers but here's how I did it with Google auth on Android:

Android:

```kotlin
activity.startActivityForResult(
        googleSignInClient.signInIntent,
        object : ActivityWithResultListener.OnActivityResultListener {
          override fun onActivityResult(resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
            if (data != null) {
              val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.idToken!!, null)
              idToken = account.idToken!!

              // Then pass the token to your webview via a JS interface
       }
)
```

Web:

```js
const idTokenFromApp = AndroidBridge.getAuthToken(); // This is the idToken from the Android code above
if (idTokenFromApp) {
    // from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin
    // Build Firebase credential with the Google ID token.
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider#static-credential
    const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idTokenFromApp);

    // Sign in with credential from the Google user.
    firebase.auth.signInWithCredential(credential).catch((error) => {
      // Handle Errors here.
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;

      logError(`Error logging in: ${errorCode} ${errorMessage} token: ${idTokenFromApp}`, error);
    });
}
```

Comment: This would work, but it may be less secure. I'm not sure how easily it would be for some nefarious app to intercept the android intent and grab the auth token. 
With custom tokens, they can only be used once, so they are a bit more secure.