# Firebase Auth: How to sign in using id token?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to share anonymous user sessions with Firebase Auth?

What I would like to is to get the current id token:

```dart
final idToken = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.getIdToken();
```

Then, use this `idToken` to authenticate the same anonymous user in a different app.

```dart
FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithToken(idToken);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `signInWithCustomToken()` method, you can use a custom auth token to sign in a user on different website. As documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens)

> Firebase gives you complete control over authentication by allowing
> you to authenticate users or devices using secure JSON Web Tokens
> (JWTs). You generate these tokens on your server, pass them back to a
> client device, and then use them to authenticate via the
> `signInWithCustomToken()` method.
>
> You can create a custom token with the Firebase Admin SDK, or you can
> use a third-party JWT library if your server is written in a language
> which Firebase does not natively support.
>
> The Firebase Admin SDK has a built-in method for creating custom
> tokens. At a minimum, you need to provide a uid, which can be any
> string but should uniquely identify the user or device you are
> authenticating. These tokens expire after one hour.
>
> After you create a custom token, you should send it to your client
> app. The client app authenticates with the custom token by calling
> `signInWithCustomToken()`

Also check out these links for more information and examples:

[Authenticate with Firebase Using a Custom Authentication System](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/custom-auth)

[Firebase auth - login user from app in website](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46841333/18265638)

[How to use the same firebase anonymous user in a flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54863420/how-to-use-the-same-firebase-anonymous-user-in-a-flutter-app)

Comment: Thank you! The second link is especially helpful. From what I understand, I would need to implement a custom token mechanism, then can use `signInWithCustomToken` method.

Comment: Yes, you will need to implement a custom token mechanism